# Not able to update href of element that is echoed in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have some jQuery below (you can see I'm targeting the ID that is being echoed in PHP):

```
  var pdf = [];
  var postNumber = $("div[id^='product-']").attr("id").replace('product-', '');

  var AWS = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/waclighting-images/SPECSHEET_PDF/";

  pdf[28163] = AWS + "R3CRPT_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28164] = AWS + "R3CRPT_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28165] = AWS + "R3CRWT_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28166] = AWS + "R3CRDL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28167] = AWS + "R3CRPL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28168] = AWS + "R3CRWL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28169] = AWS + "R3CSDT_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28170] = AWS + "R3CSPT_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28171] = AWS + "R3CSDL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28172] = AWS + "R3CSPL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";
  pdf[28173] = AWS + "R3CSWL_DIMTOWARM_SPSHT.pdf";

  $('#dtw-' + postNumber).attr('href', pdf[postNumber]);
```

And it is trying to update the URL shown in the above array based on PHP that is echoed like below:

```
 <?php if( $housingPPID != null ) {     #test
        echo ('
        <ul id="spec-sheet-option" class="downloadContainer">
            <li><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/waclighting-images/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.PDF" target="_blank">Standard</a></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i><a href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/waclighting-images/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.PDF" id="dtw-'.$post->ID . '" target="_blank">Dim-to-Warm</a></li>
        </ul>
        '); 
} ?>
```

But for some reason it isn't updating the HREF? IS there some race condition or do I need AJAX? There is no error in console, the URL is just staying the same as it is in the PHP (https://s3.amazonaws.com/waclighting-images/SPECSHEET_PDF/R3CRDT_SPSHT.PDF)

**EDIT** The javascript file is loaded in the footer.

Comment: can you make sure the `postNumber ` and the `$post->ID` are the same ?

Comment: Yes they are, at least in the browser they are. The ID is shown correctly. I'm losing my mind over this.

Comment: Ok and how are you trigger the JS code above ?

Comment: wp_enque_script and is being loaded in the footer.

Comment: Can you try to place this code into a `$(document).ready(function() {... })`?

Comment: It's within that already .. There is a little more in the code.

Comment: Why aren't you just setting the correct href in the PHP code using this logic?

Comment: It should still work client side though no?

Comment: @rec0nstr if you don't need to update it after the page is loaded. Yes.

Comment: **attr("id").replace('product-', '')** looks like you are trying to make the ID numeric, which is not allowed. It must start with a letter.

Comment: No there is another variable that starts with `product-`

Comment: How would I do this within the PHP? I'm not quite as good at it.

Comment: @rec0nstr  You would just check `$post->ID` against the list of IDs that you currently have in your JavaScript, and assign the correct href value accordingly.  [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will probably come in handy.

Comment: @PatrickQ: I don't quite get it .. the dynamic assignment part. Like how would I assign the $post->ID correctly withi `in_array()` based on whichever post ID I was on?

Comment: I've tested your code and it works on my end. If I inspect the link, it gets replaced with the url from the pdf list. Are you sure both postNumber and post -> Id are the same? Do you have somewhere another element with the same ID? PHP runs first, then your javascript code, so no issues there.

Comment: (i've tested this by defining the `var postNumber` manually because I have no idea what the `product-' element looks like, so the issue might be getting that postNumber or a double ID-declaration in your code)

Comment: @rec0nstr  It would probably help if you included the _rendered_ HTML in your question, along with a little more of the code.  It is not clear if any of what you posted above is run within loops, for example, which would change the situation.

Comment: Yes, jQuery and PHP have nothing to do with each other. Pick a direction and revise to clarify, please.